# How to drop rows with nulls in one column pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and I would like to drop all rows with NULL value in one of the columns (string). I can easily get the count of that:

```
df.filter(df.col_X.isNull()).count()
```

I have tried dropping it using following command. It executes but the count still returns as positive

```
df.filter(df.col_X.isNull()).drop()
```

I tried different attempts but it returns 'object is not callable' error.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Dataframes are immutable. so just applying a filter that removes not null values will create a new dataframe which wouldn't have the records with null values.

```
df = df.filter(df.col_X. isNotNull())
```

Answer (score 57):

Use either `drop` with `subset`:

```
df.na.drop(subset=["col_X"])
```

or `isNotNull()`

```
df.filter(df.col_X.isNotNull())
```

Comment: which is faster?

Comment: subset can have multiple values as well: `subset=["attribute1", "attribute2"]`

Answer (score 12):

if you want to drop any row in which any value is null, use

```
df.na.drop()  //same as df.na.drop("any") default is "any"
```

to drop only if all values are null for that row, use

```
df.na.drop("all")
```

to drop by passing a column list, use

```
df.na.drop("all", Seq("col1", "col2", "col3"))
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question.

Comment: what if I have to drop rows where col1 and col2 both have the null values, if only one has the null value, the row should not be dropped.

Answer (score 7):

another variation is:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = df.where(col("columnName").isNotNull())
```

Answer (score 4):

you can add empty string condition also somtimes

```
df = df.filter(df.col_X. isNotNull() | df.col_X != "")
```

Comment: should use & instead of | and the correct syntax is : df = df.filter(df.col_X.isNotNull() & (df.col_X!="")==True)

Answer (score 1):

You can use expr() functions that accept SQL-like query syntax.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

filteredDF = rawDF.filter(expr("col_X is not null")).filter("col_Y is not null")
```